# command for multiple input and multiple output

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, cut

I am performing some operations using the grep, sed, and cut commands on a Linux machinete:

```
zgrep -A1 "^module" *.v.gz | sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p' | cut -f1 -d"("
```

This is being run on files with the extension `.v.gz` and I want the output files to have a `.txt` extension instead.

For example, input filename:

```
abcd.v.gz
efgh.v.gz
ijkl.v.gz
mnop.v.gz
```

output filename

```
abcd.txt
efgh.txt
ijkl.txt
mnop.txt
```

So I want to keep the same file name prefix, but change the extension. How can I do this for an arbitrary number of files?

Comment: Regarding ` using the grep, sed, and cut` - any time you find yourself chaining together multiple Unix commands for manipulating text there's an excellent chance you could do the same with a single awk script.

Answer (score 1):

I use a shell loop in this type of case:

```bash
for file in *.v.gz; do zgrep -A1 "^module" "$file" | sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p' | cut -f1 -d"(" > $(basename "$file" .v.gz).txt; done
```

You may even not need the `basename` command if your shell has a primitive for that kind of operation.

As a complete shell script, it would look like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.v.gz
do
    zgrep -A1 "^module" "$file" | sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p' | cut -f1 -d"(" > $(basename "$file" .v.gz).txt
done
```

Comment: @Igeorget i have no idea about shell scripting

Comment: it's giving me an error as -script_shell.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file,

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. Sorry I forgot the end of the loop... the "done" keyword